# how to trigger Suspense with event-handler / react-query

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

im trying to show fallback ui when event triggered with invalidate query

i make example with codeSandbox, [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-easley-pgz0uz?file=/src/App.js)

i guess, suspense did not catch when fetching in Effect and event handler.
[react docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense)

i want to know two answers.

- did i guess correct?
- if i guess corret then, what is the best options when using invalidateQuery with event handler (isRefetching?, or make throw Promise Wrapping function?)

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-easley-pgz0uz?file=/src/App.js)

- trying to show Suspense fallback ui when click button with react query

Answer (score 0):

> did i guess correct?

no :)

> what is the best options when using invalidateQuery with event handler

with suspense, react-query will only show the suspense fallback if there is no data to show instead. When you have data in the cache, and you invalidate a query, it will make a background refetch, meaning the stale data will still be preferred over a loading state. If it helps your mental model, it's similar to React transitions.

so if you want to show a hard loading state, you have to remove data from the cache. The best way for your example is to replace `invalidateQueries` with `resetQueries`, as `reset` will reset your query to its initial state (which means: no data), and then trigger a refetch, at which point react-query will see that there is no data in the cache, so it will try to show a hard loading state, which means to show the suspense fallback.

Here's a fork of your sandbox with the working version: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-northcutt-2wpqrx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much for your lucid answer. It helped me a lot and troubleshooting that I didn't know.

I have two more questions to ask. 

* If the parent and child components are using the same query key and there is also a suspense wrapped around the parent. Is it possible to prevent the parent component from being suspended, so that only the child component's query is detected by the suspense and the parent query is not detected when it is reset?

* Is there any difference between handling it with the return value of a query like isRefetching and handling it through Suspense?